# Jmeter- Abnormal Response Body

Tags: html, jmeter, performance-testing, httpresponse

Response Code:200,Actual Response: [Get Request Response Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwsQU.png)

Response Code:200,Expected Response: HTML format Example-[HTML Response Eg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlPu5.png)

Answer (score 0):

The response doesn't necessary has to be HTML Depending on the response [content type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) it can be:

- compressed (i.e. [gzipped](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/))
- [encrypted](https://www.locklizard.com/html-encryption/)
- [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) (i.e. if you're downloading an image or a file)

If you're getting HTML response in the browser and the different one in JMeter - make sure that [JMeter sends the same request as the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), check:

- request [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
- request body
- request [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

and given you will be sending the same request you will be getting the same response.

Comment: I am sending the exact same request similar to browser.
Response Code, Response Headers are fine, just there is some weird formatting in the Response Body shown in above screenshot.